# No skyx texture on Gzweb

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

While on Gazebo SkyX works as expected, it doesn't seem so on Gzweb for me. We set it after sunset to show the starry sky on moon, but the sky is all blacked out, no stars, Sun and the earth (as [we customized](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8401/remove-the-flaring-edge-of-moonearth-in-skyx/)).

[image: no starry sky]

I found that the files in `skyx` folders in Gazebo and Gzweb are slightly different, but replacing Gzweb's dir (gzweb/http/client/assets/media/skyx) with the one from Gazebo didn't solve the issue.

Using Gazebo (2.2.5), Ubuntu 14.04, Gzweb 1.2.0 with the following commit.

```
changeset:   840:a166e0734e7d
tag:         tip
date:        Fri Jan 30 09:44:59 2015 -0800
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8421/no-skyx-texture-on-gzweb/) by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 118 on 2015-04-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

ya unfortunately sky is not yet supported in gzweb. It's currently ignoring the  sdf element.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on 2015-04-15**:
Thanks, I opened an enhancement ticket. https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gzweb/issue/67/implement-sky